# how do i stream a video in my server to my computer?

Tags: server, vlc, stream

i have an .avi file in my server, my server is running ubuntu 10.04 lts. normally i would download the .avi file to my computer. but the .avi file is huge so i would like to stream it if it is possible.

i read that i can do that with vlc. but after trying so hard i still couldn't make it stream.. please help me with this..

Answer (score 2):

Share your video files folder on the server via samba, and once you navigate to the folder in Nautilus, you just have to click on it, and Movie Player will begin playing it as soon as it buffers a bit.

Answer (score 0):

VLC is definitely the way to go here.

There are numerous tutorials on YouTube that can take you step-by-step through the process. I'd suggest searching there.