# Easiest way to stream videos from my server?

Tags: video, vlc, streaming

I'd like to download movie torrents from my Ubuntu server as its download speed is much higher than at home. However, it is pretty pointless if I then have to download the movie from my server to my laptop so I thought a good compromise would be to stream the movies. What is the easiest way to do so? My only requirements are that everything on the server side should be done through the command line (ssh) and if possible, minimal dependencies. My media player is VLC but I wouldn't mind using a web browser to watch the videos.

Related question: [how do i stream a video in my server to my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37374/how-do-i-stream-a-video-in-my-server-to-my-computer)

Answer (score 4):

use ssh -X with xauth, and run vlc on the server. It's fairly easy to stream videos using vlc. Howver this solution uses too much bandwidth to be usable.

What you should use instead is a network filesystem, just hit `ctrl-l` in nautilus, and then type `sftp://user@my-server:port/folder` and open up your movies directly off the server. This will use some cpu on both the server and client for the encryption, if that is a problem you can set up NFS.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend uShare.

The link above have instructions to install and configure it 
(it's for Xbox, but you can adapt for laptop use skipping the xbox options)

http://nexus172.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/how-to-stream-video-to-your-xbox360-using-ubuntu-ushare/