# How to make file and streaming server?

Tags: server, files, streaming

I have this desktop computer im not using. I want to use it for file storage for all types of files. I also want to share these files to windows computers and stream video to tablet and phones. The streaming will be only localy

What software do i need and how would i go about this?

Comment: 1. file server: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126850/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-server-as-file-server 2. streaming: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168902/easiest-way-to-stream-videos-from-my-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If your clients are going to be running windows, I would recomend Samba. Samba can be enabled by right clicking on a folder->Properties->Share.

To mount your drives on your windows machines just write:

> \\ipforyourserver\sharedfoldername

in RUN